# How to set/change default article category in Joomla 3.10?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, category, default

When I create a new article, there is a default category of "Uncategorised".  Is there any way to set a different default article category instead of the native default "Uncategorised" category?

In the Joomla settings, I don't see any setting option where I can change it.  Can this be changed through the database or by modifying Joomla's PHP code?

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange! Please take the [tour] to learn about all functionality of JSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the **default category is** the **first category** in the list.

To change the default category, go to Content > Categories. Click on the first column so that the order of the categories is on ordering. Click on the 3 vertical dots of the category that you want to make the default category and drag it to the top.

Comment: In my case, the category I want to set as the default article category is a subcategory of the first ordered category.
Example.
Category 1
    -Subcategory 1
    -Subcategory 2
Category 2

I want the default category to be -Subcategory 1

Comment: Joomla takes the first category, so you cannot set a sub category as default category.

Answer (score 1):

As well as re-ordering to change which category is set as default as per pe7er's reply above, you can always edit the Uncategorised category and rename it to something more useful for your requirements.